# SQL query return name and count of specific attributes across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given multiple tables I'm trying to write a query that returns the names that satisfies a specific count clause.

I have the tables:

```
 genre(genre, movieid)
 moviedirectors(movieid, directorid)
 directors(directorid, firstname, lastname)
```

I want to write a query that returns the first and last name of directors that directed at least 50 movies of the genre comedy, and return that number as well.

This is what I have

```
select d.fname, d.lname, count(*)
from genre g, directors d, moviedirectors md
where g.genre='Comedy' and g.movieid=md.movieid and    
                  md.directorid=d.directorid
group by d.id
having count(*) >= 50
```

I believe this should be correct but when I run this query on the command line it never finishes. I waited 30 minutes and got no results.

Comment: How large is your table?  Note that you are including non-aggregate columns in your `SELECT` clause, which would not even run in most databases (q.v. the answer by @varontron below).

Comment: This looks like a homework problem I had in a mooc class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need inner joins:

```
SELECT d.fname
       d.lname
FROM genre g 
INNER JOIN moviedirectors md
    ON g.movieid = md.movieid
INNER JOIN directors d
    ON md.directorid = d.directorid
WHERE g.genre = 'Comedy' 
GROUP BY d.fname,        -- group by columns in select
         d.lname
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50
```

Comment: Is there a difference between typing INNER JOIN and JOIN. I had previously used JOIN and it was not running. Also why did you group by d.fname, d.lname rather than by d.id?

Comment: @Misohappi . . . `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

select c.firstname,c.lastname,count(e.movieid) from (select a.* from directors a,movie b where b.genre = 'Comedy' and b.movieid=a.movieid)d,directors c where c.directorid=d.directorid group by e.movieid having count(e.movieid)>50;